# Ubuntu Server 16.10 won't allow connection through open port 80

Tags: networking, server, firewall, ufw, nodejs

I am attempting to run a gulp (node.js) server on port 80. I previously had an Nginx server running fine on this port, and was able to access from the outside. As you can see from the `curl` command, the server process is running and serving correctly to localhost (I have hostname set to '0.0.0.0' in gulp file, and have also tried setting this to '127.0.0.1'):

[image: Serving internally]

However, when I type the public IP into the browser from a remote machine nothing happens. Likewise when I run a `curl` on the public IP (so it's not a malformed html/php issue or anything like that) from another machine. Although a `curl` to the public IP from the machine itself works fine.

Here is a picture of the server process initial output:

[image: gulp server process]

What else could be blocking this connection? I haven't added any additional firewalls to the system myself.

`iptables -L` outputs the following:

```
Chain ufw-user-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http /* 'dapp_Nginx%20HTTP' */
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:8000
DROP       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:8000
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:http
```

So I'm wondering if

`DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http /* 'dapp_Nginx%20HTTP' */`

Might be the problem, and maybe it's denying more than just Nginx (though surely it should be?)? If so how do I remove this particular deny rule using iptables? If not I'm kind of at a loss for what might be causing the problem.

(I can included the full `iptables -L` output if anyone feels they need it.)

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, in the end it was the Nginx rule, which I would have thought would be specific to Nginx, but apparently blocked off the whole port, even after port 80 was specifically opened with ufw.

Fixed like this:

```
iptables -D ufw-user-input 1
```